# Django : customizing FileField value while editing a model

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-forms, django-file-upload

I've got a model, with `FileField`. When I edit this model in a view, I want to change the "current" value of `FileField` which gets displayed in the view form. Let me explain.

**models.py:**

```
class DemoVar_model(models.Model):
    ...
    Welcome_sound=models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d')
```

**forms.py:**

```
class DemoVar_addform(ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = DemoVar_model
```

**views.py:**

```
soundform = DemoVar_addform(instance=ivrobj)
....
return render_to_response(template,{'soundform':soundform}, ....)
```

Now I want to edit this model in my view. When I look in browser, I see the form being displayed as

```
Welcome sound: Currently: welcome_files/2011/04/27/15_35_58_ojCompany.wav.mp3 
Change : <Choose File button>
```

I want to change this "Currently" value, which describes the whole path of the file as it exits on my server. I want to trim this string to just the filename without the path. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to override the ClearableFileInput that is currently used, to change the way it's displayed.

Here is the code of the new `ShortNameFileInput` which inherit from the default `ClearableFileInput` with just a change on the 19th line to only show the file name:

```
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput
import os
# missing imports
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from cgi import escape
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode

class ShortNameClarableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        substitutions = {
            'initial_text': self.initial_text,
            'input_text': self.input_text,
            'clear_template': '',
            'clear_checkbox_label': self.clear_checkbox_label,
        }
        template = u'%(input)s'
        substitutions['input'] = super(ClearableFileInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)

        if value and hasattr(value, "url"):
            template = self.template_with_initial
            substitutions['initial'] = (u'<a href="%s">%s</a>'
                                        % (escape(value.url),
                                           escape(force_unicode(os.path.basename(value.url))))) # I just changed this line
            if not self.is_required:
                checkbox_name = self.clear_checkbox_name(name)
                checkbox_id = self.clear_checkbox_id(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_name'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_name)
                substitutions['clear_checkbox_id'] = conditional_escape(checkbox_id)
                substitutions['clear'] = CheckboxInput().render(checkbox_name, False, attrs={'id': checkbox_id})
                substitutions['clear_template'] = self.template_with_clear % substitutions

        return mark_safe(template % substitutions)
```

To use it in your form, you'll have to manually set the widget you want to use :

```
class DemoVar_addform(ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = DemoVar_model
        widgets = {
            'Welcome_sound': ShortNameClarableFileInput,
        }
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Why can't I derive from FileInput instead of ClearableFileInput?

Answer (score 9):

If you want an easier way and avoid to rewrite the render logic of the widget, you can do a little hack.

```
from os import path
from django import forms


class FormatString(str):

    def format(self, *args, **kwargs):
        arguments = list(args)
        arguments[1] = path.basename(arguments[1])
        return super(FormatString, self).format(*arguments, **kwargs)


 class ClearableFileInput(forms.ClearableFileInput):

     url_markup_template = FormatString('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>')
```

And then manually set the widget for the field.

```
class DemoVar_addform(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DemoVar_model
        widgets = {
            'Welcome_sound': ClearableFileInput,
        }
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach than the accepted answer and does not result in any unnecessary code duplication.

Answer (score 3):

## **Django 1.10.x or older version**

---

The easiest way is to override the `template_substitution_values` in default `ClearableFileInput` django widget that will be used later in rendering the form. This is a much cleaner approach that does not result in any unnecessary code duplication.

```
from os import path
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape

class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    def get_template_substitution_values(self, value):
        """
        Return value-related substitutions.
        """
        return {
            'initial': conditional_escape(path.basename(value.name)),
            'initial_url': conditional_escape(value.url),
        }
```

then use the widget in **forms.py** as follow:

```
class DemoVar_addform(ModelForm):
    Welcome_sound = forms.FileField(widget=CustomClearableFileInput)    
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = DemoVar_model

    ...
```

## **Django 1.11.x or later versions**

---

Check [ImageField / FileField Django form Currently unable to trim the path to filename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897482/5658350).

Comment: i tried this but nothing happen to "Currently" to trim the filepath. I put my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887158/imagefield-filefield-django-form-currently-unable-to-trim-the-path-to-filename @DhiaTN

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it, would be to write a custom form widget and override the render method.